# The attachToapplication shows timeout handshake

Tags: python, robotframework, squish

Integrating squish with robotframework using  python library.
Creating the test case using attach to application ${autname} ${host}  ${port} ${timeout}
Shows a timeout expired during hand shake
How to solve that?

Tried to increase the time but still failing.
Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is best to show what you did/do, instead of paraphrasing/summarizing what you do. ("I did everything correctly, but something does not work" vs. "I did A, B, then C. And when I do D, I get this error message: "exact error message here".) In case of Squish and the robotframework, you are probably using Squish's squishtest module, which is explained in the manual and the KB article https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/using-squish-module-python-scripts-applications/. I recommend trying to get this working without the robotframework first.